# BaseURL field not available

Tags: craft3

First time I install CraftCMS and during the wizard as well as in the Control Panel the fields for BaseURL are displayed like this:

[image]

I got passed the wizard by using the comand line tool but now can't create a new site.

Am I missing some sort of option / configuration? (running on Windows Server 2019 / IIS 10 / PostgreSQL 12.2)

**Edit**: I just noticed the same behavior within the email settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On our servers we only have the Internet Explorer installed which results in this behavior.

When accessing the site with Chrome or Firefox everything works as it should.